# Retrive which is the default mail app iOS

Tags: ios, email, default, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

since in iOS 14 it is possibile to change the default app for emails, and also the browser.
How can I retrive which is the default app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming that since this is a year old you never found this out?

Comment: 2023, we still can't.